# Incorrectly displayed background in the mobile version. HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, adaptive-design

When expanding <500px in the computer version, the background looks like it should. In the mobile version of the background "curve".

html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
body {
    background-image: url("../img/background-body-500px.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

}

## PC web

[image: PC web]

## Mobile web

[image: Mobile web]

Comment: Do you have the full html and css of that page for us, or perhaps the link to the page? There is more going on than just this css snippet. It looks like the image is set as 500px width. But I can't know for sure. So if you have more info, that would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to be able to debug this with a [MCVE]